# How to convert 2014-06-24T22:33:49.180Z format into Y-m-d H:i:s in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I received `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object` error when I tried to use format on a json converted date string of `2014-06-24T22:37:13.151Z` (specifically from `new Date()` )

```
$objData->myCodeCreateDate="2014-06-24T22:39:34.652Z"
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', $objData->myCodeCreateDate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Seems quite obvious that the problem is you're using an empty string as the date to format, no? I think `$objData->myCodeCreateDate=""` should be `$objData->myCodeCreateDate = date();`

Comment: @SharkoMirkwood Thank you for point out, actually I forgot to paste the date. Here it is. My Apology

Answer (score 4):

That looks like the way Amazon sends back its timestamp, which follows this format in UTC time:

> `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z`.

You can edit your `createFromFormat` format to the above, and it should work.

Here's an example with your data:

```
$date_string = "2014-06-24T22:37:13.151Z";
$date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', $date_string);
echo $date_object->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```